# How to build a pre-selected option for a selectField in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

([This was asked before but it has no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588667/multiselectfield-with-pre-selected-options-in-yesod)).

I have a list of countries in a database:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings] [persistLowerCase|
Country
  name Text
  UniqueCountryName name
  deriving Show
|]
```

And I can show a form to select one of them:

```
countries = do
  rows <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc CountryName]
  optionsPairs $ map (\ r -> (countryName $ entityVal r, entityKey r)) rows

surveyForm :: Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult SurveyAnswerSet, Widget)
surveyForm extra = do
  (countryR, countryV) <- mreq (selectField countries) "" Nothing
```

I know that I should replace the `Nothing` in the last line with the desired default value but I still don't get how to do it. Looking at the [`mreq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.4.7.1/docs/Yesod-Form-Functions.html#g:3) and the [`optionsPairs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.4.9/docs/Yesod-Form-Fields.html#v:optionsPairs) signatures my thought was that in this case I should provide a `Maybe Option` with the default country but my attempts have raised so many type errors that probably I am quite far from the right answer.

The Yesod book has an example using seems more simple than what I tried to achieve so I am not sure how to extrapolate it.

By the way I am getting the default country from the database so I don't need to hardcode its internal id:

```
defaultCountry = do
  row <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueCountryName $ countryName "United States"
  (countryName $ entityVal row, entityKey row)
```

When I pass it as an argument to `mreq` I get the following errors:

> Couldn't match type ‘(,) Text’ with ‘HandlerFor site’
>   Expected type: HandlerFor site (Key record)
>     Actual type: (Text, Key record)

That's on the last line of the of the `defaultContry` function (`(countryName $ entityVal row, entityKey row)`). I understand that I should take the `Key record` from the pair and return it in a `HandlerFor site` but at the same time I also get:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe (Key Country)’
>               with actual type ‘HandlerFor site0 (Key record0)’

In the `(countryR, countryV) <- mreq (selectField countries) "" defaultCountry` line. I interprete this as "you are passing me a `HandlerFor site0 (Key record0)` but I only accept `Maybe (Key Country)` which seems in conflict with the first error...

In the `(countryName $ entityVal row, entityKey row)` line I also see:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Entity Country’
>               with actual type ‘Maybe (Entity Country)’

in the `row` argument. I understand that I should extract the `Entity Country` from the `Maybe` but if I pattern match and pass just the `Entity Country` (i. e.: `Just (Entity countryId country) -> (countryName $ entityVal (Entity countryId country), entityKey (Entity countryId country)`) I still get the first error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default value in mreq is not the default value of the OptionPair  but the default  use to fill countryR (or countryV , which ever contains the value). In your case , it is probably either a Text or a CountryKey.

Comment: The types are a little confusing here - do you think you could annotate `defaultCountry` and `countries`? Otherwise, I can't see why you wouldn't do `(name, key) <- defaultCountry; (countryR, countryV) <- mreq (selectField countries) "" (Just key)`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated my question with the GHC errors. They include the expected and provided types. I tried to follow them but I get lost because two of them seems to be in conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this looks like a few type errors. The first

> Couldn't match type ‘(,) Text’ with ‘HandlerFor site’ Expected type: HandlerFor site (Key record) Actual type: (Text, Key record)

comes from not using `return` in your `do` notation to lift the value to the monad:

```
defaultCountry :: HandlerFor site (Text, Key record)
defaultCountry = do
  row <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueCountryName $ countryName "United States"
  return (countryName $ entityVal row, entityKey row)
```

The error on `row`

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Entity Country’ with actual type ‘Maybe (Entity Country)’

is because it's a `Maybe`, so let's correct that

```
defaultCountry :: HandlerFor site (Text, Key record)
defaultCountry = do
  Just row <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueCountryName $ countryName "United States"
  return (countryName $ entityVal row, entityKey row)
```

Now that `defaultCountry` is a good monad, you should be able to use it in your other code. But be careful of that third error

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe (Key Country)’ with actual type ‘HandlerFor site0 (Key record0)’

You need to unwrap the value from the `HandlerFor` monad, and rewrap it in a `Maybe`

```
surveyForm :: Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult SurveyAnswerSet, Widget)
surveyForm extra = do
  (defaultName, defaultKey) <- defaultCountry -- (defaultName, defaultKey) :: (Text, Key record)
  (countryR, countryV) <- mreq (selectField countries) "" (Just defaultKey)
```

Comment: I'm still seeing several errors, but new ones! If I apply only the changes to the `defaultCountry` function I get `Couldn't match type ‘record’ with ‘Country’ ‘record’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: defaultCountry :: forall site record. HandlerFor site (Text, Key record) at app/Main.hs:54:1-52 Expected type: HandlerFor site (Text, Key record) Actual type: HandlerFor site (Text, Key Country)`

Comment: Then just replace `record` in the type declarations with `Country`.

Comment: Oh, right  but now the error is even weirder `Couldn't match type ‘BaseBackend (YesodPersistBackend site)’ with ‘SqlBackend’ arising from a use of ‘getBy’`. I stripped down my attempt to this https://gist.github.com/tssm/3a503fb60cde023d05a33cf2248e7d40 (I had several other form fields and it worked until I tried to preselect an option)

Comment: From the code you've shared, it looks like you should then put `App` instead of `site` in the type signatures.

Comment: That reduced the errors enough for me to figure it out the next steps: 1. to get the default country from the database I should use just `UniqueCountryName` not `UniqueCountryName $ countryName)` and 2. `defaultContry` must be lifted when in `SurveyForm` to being able to get `defaultKey`. Thank you very much for all your patience!